# Text Editor in Python Spyder in Anaconda constantly lagging

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, text-editor, lag

I have 3.8.8 Python and 4.10.3 Anaconda Spyder, and I use the 2019 MacBook Pro (16 inches screen).

When I text in the text editor in Spyder, my text is constantly lagging. The faster I type, the more lags there are. When I delete texts, the faster I press the delete button, the more lags there are.

However, this only happens if I maximizes the Spyder window. The smaller the window gets, the less lagging there are. When the window is small enough (such that it takes up only 1/4 of the 16 inches screen), the lagging problem disappears.

Other coding interfaces don't have the lagging issue, regardless of the window size. For example, Visual Studio Code doens't have the issue.

My presciption is super high (like 12) so I need to use super big screens to work. I don't want to only use 1/4 of the screen and I don't like the lagging either.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Not an answer but I personally think vs code is much better than spyder for python anyway, can you not start using that in place of spyder?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using Big Sur? Maybe this could be useful: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#troubleshooting-macos-bigsur

Answer (score 0):

Personally this sounds like a hardware issue, otherwise try to keep a low usage on ram, and CPU. I would maybe see if there are also communication errors, I can’t help with that as I don’t use MacOS, larger screens do also cause more lag if possible choose dark them so the pixels don’t take up too much power (I think) I had the same issue

Comment: I try using spyder on a 13 inch macboko pro and i notice that there is still some lagging, but to a lesser extent. i think there's something wrong with spyder that causes lagging becuase other coding softwares are perfectly fine. but i think you're right about larger screen having more lag.

Comment: could you explain what communication errors are? I've never heard of them

Comment: SO what you need to do is get a fresh install make sure that there were no interruptions if it end up lagging out again I can help Make sure to use dark mode so the screen is not using as many pixels